# POST method - "message": "The given data was invalid." in Laravel 8

Tags: mysql, laravel, api

I'm creating an api in Laravel 8. Then after creating my *RegisterController* I'm getting a message error:

```
HTTP/1.1 422 Unprocessable Entity
Host: 127.0.0.1:8000
Date: Sat, 27 Feb 2021 14:30:24 GMT, Sat, 27 Feb 2021 14:30:24 GMT
Connection: close
X-Powered-By: PHP/7.3.27
Cache-Control: no-cache, private
Content-Type: application/json
X-RateLimit-Limit: 60
X-RateLimit-Remaining: 59
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *

{
"message": "The given data was invalid.",
"errors": {
"name": [
  "The name field is required."
],
"username": [
  "The username field is required."
],
"email": [
  "The email field is required."
],
"password": [
  "The password field is required."
]
}
}
```

This is my *RegisterController*,

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $this->validate($request, [
        'name' => 'required|max:255',
        'username' => 'required|max:255',
        'email' => 'required|email|max:255',
        'password' => 'required|confirmed',
    ]);

    User::create([
        'name' => $request->name,
        'username' => $request->username,
        'email' => $request->email,
        'password' => Hash::make($request->password),
    ]);
    
    auth()->attempt($request->only('email', 'password'));

}

protected function registered(Request $request, User $user)
{
    $user->generateToken();

    return response()->json(['data' => $user->toArray()], 201);
}
```

and this is the *model*,

```
protected $fillable = [
    'name',
    'username',
    'email',
    'password',
];

public function generateToken()
{
    $this->api_token = str_random(60);
    $this->save();

    return $this->api_token;
}
```

And also I'm using *Rest client* in *VsCode* to run the methods, this is the test:

```
POST http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/register
Content-Type: application/json
Accept: application/json

{
    "name": "Test User",
    "username": "TestUsername",
    "email": "Test@gmail.com",
    "password": "Testpass"
}
```

I hope someone knows why I'm getting this error as a result. I'd greatly appreciate the help. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The 422 error is the validation error. Which is generating from your this block of code.

```
         $this->validate($request, [
             'name' => 'required|max:255',
             'username' => 'required|max:255',
             'email' => 'required|email|max:255',
             'password' => 'required|confirmed',
          ]);
```

It is expected if you don't provide any values to the required variables. I think you are making mistake to send data using Rest client.

Answer (score 0):

try:
{
"name": "**Test_User**",
"username": "TestUsername",
"email": "Test@gmail.com",
"password": "Testpass"
}

Comment: It would be helpful if you put a bit more beef to your answer: why was there an error, and what have you changed, and why will that solve the problem?